# Import package from parent directory

Tags: python, import, directory, package

I use python 3.10

This is my tree directory:

```
.
├── packages
│   ├── __init__.py
│   └── my_func.py
└── run
    └── run.py
```

I want to import function from my_func.py to run.py, and then run run.py from run directory.

**run.py:**

```
# import os
# import sys


# sys.path.append(os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))))

from my_func import func1

func1()
```

**my_func.py:**

```
def func1():
    print("OK")
```

I've tried below code and it works.

```
import os
import sys


sys.path.append(os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))))
from my_func import func1
```

But I want to import *func1* without "trick" with sys.path.append. It is possible?